# "Dynamic" handler?

Tags: jquery

Suppose I have this code :

```
$('.mask-preview:not(.selected)').click(function () {
    $('.mask-preview.selected').removeClass('selected');
    $(this).addClass('selected');
    console.log("added");
});
```

now, on element with `class="mask-preview selected"` this handler is not invoked. When I call it on a element without `selected`, the handler is invoked, and the class is added.

But now, I can still call that handler on that element, also if `selected` is added. In fact "handler" is not "updated" to the DOM. Is there a way to do this dynamically?

I'll get rid to check every time `if(element.hasClass())`

Comment: You don't have to check `element.hasClass`, if you just toggle it - `toggleClass` would suffice. ) And technically there's a way of using delegation, but, frankly speaking, I don't understand how it'd be better. )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The binding is only happening once, and is not altered when you change the element.

It's simplest to just check the class inside the callback.

```
$('.mask-preview').on('click', function() {
    if ($(this).hasClass('selected')) {
        ...
    } else {
        ...
    }
});
```

**EDIT** this answer updated, thanks to comments pointing out that the selector in `.on` only applies to descendants, and not the registered element itself.

Comment: `.mask-preview` **is/was** `.selected`. It is not the parent of `.selected`.

Comment: Uhm, I think about it, but will be more expensive in resource terms, isnt it?

Comment: @markzzz I don't believe that's significantly more expensive than just performing the test using a test inside the callback.

Comment: @Alnitak : would be nice know the performance about these... for me is significantly :)

Comment: What I meant is that using `.on` style delegation (where the selected elements are a subset of the whole DOM) is more efficient than the old style where every event bubbled all the way up to the `document`.  But my edited answer doesn't use that anyway

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
$('#mask-preview').click(function () {
    if ( !$(this).hasClass('selected') ) {
        $(this).addClass('selected');
        console.log("added");
    } else {
        $(this).addClass('not_selected');
        console.log("added");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

may be `.live` can help you in this

```
$('.mask-preview:not(.selected)').live('click',function () {
    $('.mask-preview.selected').removeClass('selected');
    $(this).addClass('selected');
    console.log("added");
});​
```

[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6ZEmY/1/)

Comment: You can edit your previous answer and undelete it, no need to make it into several different answers. )